# CSS or SVG text clip / mask

Tags: css, svg

I am not sure if this is possible, but is there a way to make text a clipping path or a mask?

Example: If there were a layer of text above another layer of text, have the top layer "knock out" the lower layer so the background could be seen through. See the link below (sorry, I don't have enough rep yet to post images), I don't really want the border around the letters, but I added it to try and describe what I am trying to achieve.

Notice how the bottom "This is some text" string has the missing color where the top layer overlaps. The top layer of text would be transparent but would also "knock out" or apply transparency anywhere it overlaps the lower layer of text.

[image]

Comment: Please also explain how you currently do this, which of the two examples in this picture is the desired result, and please provide the code for the text you currently make this.

Comment: Is the transparency absolutely necessary, or could you just have the front text be the same color as the background?

Comment: Sorry, the desired result is the bottom line of text. Here is a better example. http://jsfiddle.net/OBCENEIKON/LDMD2/

I am wanting to achieve the first result, but that's done with setting circle-o to white. If there is a background color or image, you will end up seeing the white circle, I would rather it be transparent so that you see the image or color behind.

Comment: I know I could easily draw a circle to use as a mask, but I was hoping I could use the glyphs as a mask instead so that I could use any glyph rather than having to use a custom shape.

Comment: Is there some reason you think that replacing a `<circle>` element with a `<text>` element containing some text would not work? Did you try it? Post the code you've got so far with a mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a filter. Ideally, we'd just use two feImage's to import the source text and composite them together. But Firefox doesn't support that yet, so for cross-browser, we're stuck using a "green-screen" type effect and some careful positioning of your source text. It's a a little like using an elephant gun to kill a fly. But it does work: http://codepen.io/mullany/pen/sogvi

```
  <svg>
  <filter id="knockoutSpecial">
    <feOffset dy="150" result="pos-text"/>
    <feComposite operator="out" in2="SourceGraphic" in="pos-text" result="cut-red"/>
    <feColorMatrix in="cut-red" result="recolor1" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1
                          0 0 0 0 0.0
                          0 0 0 0 0.1
                          0 0 0 1 0"/>    
    <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" result="empty-red" type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0
                          0 1 0 0 0
                          0 0 1 0 0
                          0 -5 0 1 0"/>
    <feColorMatrix in="empty-red" result="recolor2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.5
                          0 0 0 0 0.5
                          0 0 0 0 0.5
                          0 0 0 1 0"/>
    <feComposite operator="over" in="recolor1" in2="recolor2"/>
  </filter>

  <g filter="url(#knockoutSpecial)">
    <text x="0" y="-50" font-size="84" font-weight="bold" fill="red">Cutting out text?</text>
    <text stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" fill="green" x="40" y="120" font-size="84" font-weight="bold" font-family="helvetica">No Problem....</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[image]